# wp_enqueue_scripts wont load my scripts

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

I am trying to add my custom scripts to my project but can seem to get them to load. I've never had this issue and am stumped. This is what I have in my functions.php:

```
function ex_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'backgroundJS', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/background.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'superJS' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/supersized.core.3.2.1.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ex_scripts' );
```

I know the ex_scripts function is running. I added a `echo "hello"; die();` statement to the top of the function and it worked. I also know the js filepaths are correct and that they are accessible. jQuery will load both with or without its enqueue script (because it's listed as a dependency of the lower two), but my custom scripts aren't being added.

Comment: are you using a child theme? does your theme call `wp_footer`?

Comment: Where is this code located? What file?